# iOS UIScrollView always bounces back

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make a basic proof of concept app. It uses UIScrollView with an UIImageView inside of it.

I set the image then set the contentSize of the UIScrollView but I still can't seem to scroll, it always bounces back to the start. Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing?

PS. Zooming works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.picture setImage:nil];
    [self.picture setImage:self.image];

    self.scroll.contentSize = self.picture.frame.size;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.picture;
}
```

Hi everyone ok, I've figured out what the problem was other then the fix below. It works as soon as i turn off the Autolayout option in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the image on a `UIImageView`, the frame of it does not update to the size of the new image. What you'll want to do is call the following to update the frame frame of `picture` to match the size of the image.

```
[self.picture sizeToFit];
```

On a side note, you dont need to set the image on nil on the imageView before changing it.

Comment: Cool ok, I just added it and I can see it now sets all the correct sizes in, but it still doesn't scroll. I added the below and when it stops inside i checked the value of scroll's contentSize and the content size is set to 320x460 which isn't the correct size. Which is why I think it's doing the bounce but I dunno where it's changing the contentSize.

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        int i = 0;
    }

Comment: (You can also set the frame of `self.picture` to some other value if that makes more sense for your app.)

Comment: This really isn't a much helpful way to resize the uipagecontrol, in fact doesn't even work after rotation. instead use autolayout much easier.